# Proper DI or service locator anti-pattern?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm developing an SDK and am using DI (I think incorrectly) for my classes & their dependencies. I believe I've mixed DI and a service locator. My problems are:

- Knowing where to build my DI container. I do not have a runtime/entry-point to use as a [composition root](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) - and shouldn't according to that post.
- Service lifetimes. The way I am creating my DI container is causing multiple singleton objects to be created and each class has its own DI container - I definitely want to avoid that

This [DI via Builder equivalent to service locator anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157182/is-di-via-builder-equivalent-to-service-locator-anti-pattern) seems to be what I am after but is unanswered.

I define my container with .NET DI:

```
public class ServiceProvider
{
        private Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider serviceProvider;
        protected readonly IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        public ServiceProvider()
        {
            serviceCollection.AddScoped<IScopedService, ScopedService>();
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ISingletonService, SingletonService>();
        }
}
```

Now, when ScopedService depends on SingletonService, it is done with proper constructor injection:

```
public ScopedService(ISingletonService singletonService)
{
    _singletonService = singletonService
}
```

But the consuming (end-user) classes are done via service locator, e.g.

```
private IScopedService _scopedService;
private IScopedService ScopedService
{
    get
    {
        return _scopedService ?? _scopedService = serviceProvider.GetService<IScopedService>();
    }
}
```

My consuming classes all inherit from a base class, which I believe is creating a new instance of ServiceProvider every time a class is instantiated.

```
    public abstract class ComponentBase
    {
        protected internal ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider();
    }
```

Problem: Multiple Singleton objects are being created

```
            var singleton1 = consumingClass.serviceProvider.GetService<ISingletonService>();
            var singleton2 = consumingClass.serviceProvider.GetService<ISingletonService>();

Assert.AreEqual(singleton1, singleton2) // Test failure
```

I expect the Singleton services to be the same instance. Should I make the ServiceProvider in the base class static? That would fix the issue but also seems to be trending even more in the direction of service locator anti-pattern.

Should I move to a factory-based pattern? Where I register all consuming classes in the service provider and only the factory is aware of the DI container? You would then get a class by calling a getter on the factory?

Comment: While IMO there are occasions where something resembling a service locator is the lesser of two evils, directly injecting the container into a class is definitely an anti-pattern because the dependency becomes unclear. The class can request *anything* from that container. It creates an undefined, open-ended dependency. [Here's an article](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2018/11/27/stop-worrying-love-service-locator.html) (mine) which shows an example where something like service locator might be helpful and how to minimize its evil.

Comment: I would write every single class to depend on what it should depend on. If you do that, there is pretty much always a way to configure your container to supply those dependencies. It's usually easy. If it's hard, then that's the problem to solve. Your classes will be written correctly. Solve the problem where the problem is, not by allowing it to leak into your classes.

Comment: Thank you @scotthannen that is a very useful article

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please read more at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against having your own `IServiceProvider` within the SDK similar to what was stated in the linked article.

Instead expose an extensibility point for your SDK to plug into the DI of the consumer

```
public static MySDKServiceCollectionExtensions {
    public static IServiceCollection AddMySDK(this IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddScoped<IScopedService, ScopedService>();
        services.AddSingleton<ISingletonService, SingletonService>();

        //...additional services.

        return services
    }
}
```

If your consuming components need access to these services then use explicitly dependency principle via constructor injection

```
public abstract class ComponentBase {        
    protected ISingletonService singleton;

    public ComponentBase(ISingletonService singleton) {
        this.singleton = singleton;
    }
}
```

Having `IServiceProvider` in your SDK is seen as an implementation concern that should not matter to your SDK.

> A DI Container should only be referenced from the Composition Root. All other modules should have no reference to the container.

The consuming project/application (end-user) will add your SDK in their composition root

```
//...

IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

//...Add SDK
serviceCollection.AddMySDK();

//Add my services.
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IConsumer, Consumer>()

//...
```

and use it accordingly as needed

```
public class Consumer: IConsumer {
    protected internal IScopedService service;

    protected Consumer(IScopedService service) {
        this.service = service
    }

    private IScopedService ScopedService {
        get {
            return service;
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: I really like this answer. Extension method to add my services to the end-user services is very slick. I do have a question though - in this way, will I need to register my end-user/consuming classes as services in the ServiceCollection? And retrieve with `var component = services.GetService<IConsumer>();`?

Comment: @JohnCurran yes if you want the container to do all the heavy lifting of resolving everything.

Comment: @JohnCurran but that should not be your concern. They will register their classes as desired